# I can not return a value (RXJS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I would to return a value, but I can not.. 
I do not know how I could do

The value that receives:

```
  public filterOptions: Observable<string[]>;
```

My code that I would to return:

```
    this.filterOptions = this.myForm.get('search').valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map((val) => {
        if (!val) {
          this.suscriptionSearch.unsubscribe();
          return null;
        } 
        if (this.bool) {
        const filterValue = val.trim().toLowerCase();
        const obj = {search: ''}
        obj.search = filterValue;
        this.suscriptionSearch = this.userService.searchUser(obj).subscribe((data)=>{
          let monTab:string[] = [];

          for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            monTab[index] = data[index].nom
          }

          return monTab.filter((option) => { 
            return option.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue)
          }) //the value to return

          }); 
        }
      }));
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are returning an observable. And you would not want to overwrite the observable with a new one either. If you want to have `option.toLowerCase()...` you probably would need to use a [Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject)

Comment: I actually think it is weird, that you provide a filter to the service and you again use that very same filtervalue on the received list. Ok the service likely use contains and you then check on startsWith, but wouldn't it be better to get the service enhanced so you only receive startsWith results?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution .. I share it with you.

```
    this.filterOptions = this.myForm.get('search').valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      switchMap((val) => { 
        if (this.bool) {
        const filterValue = val.trim().toLowerCase();
        const obj = {search: ''}
        obj.search = filterValue;
        return this.userService.searchUser(obj).pipe(map((data)=>{
          let monTab:string[] = [];
          for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
                monTab[index] = data[index].nom
              }
              console.log(monTab);
             return  monTab.filter((option) => { 
                    return option.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue)
                  });
        }))
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      }));
```